# network services questions

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about network services about vsftpd but there was not any anwer yet also I saw many times question related to network are answered few . why this is happen? Am should ask these kind of question in other stacks ? But I tell my self this problem happen for me in ubuntu OS may be experts in here can answer me.

The question is [How to test working of vsftpd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445296/how-to-test-working-of-vsftpd)

Comment: 48 views - that is not too bad - the problem may be that it is hard to understand what you really want.

Comment: To dear Jorge Castro, How Do i Can Say "Thank You".